# Receive external data - Magento

Tags: magento, external

First I want to say that this text was translated by Google Translate ( Excuses !).

How do I send data from an external server for my Magento store?
I looked hard for it today and found nothing basically want another system sends a notification to my Magento store and change the status of my order , I have not found a way to receiving external data in my store.

If you already have a related question I apologize.

**Edit**

This is my external file that sends the data:

```
      $fields = '';
      foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
         $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
      }

      rtrim($fields, '&');

      $post = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
      curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      var_dump($fields);

      try {
         $result = curl_exec($post);
         $info = curl_getinfo($post);
         echo curl_getinfo($post, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         echo "<br>";
         echo var_dump($info);
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $result = $e->getMessage();
         echo $e;
      }
   }

   $data = array(
      "name" => "c.bavota",
      "website" => "http://bavotasan.com",
      "twitterID" => "bavotasan"
   );

   post_to_url("http://localhost/magento/safe/teste/mostra/", $data);
?>
```

This is my controller in Magento:

```
<?php

   class Name_MyModule_TesteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

      public function mostraAction(){
         $teste = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
         echo 'Olá mundo';
         echo '<br>Teste: '.isset($teste);
      }
    }
```

ps: I'm testing with locally with WAMP

Comment: This is what the API is for. Have a read about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Really should have posted on magento.stackexchange.com. Its move there?